# Modifying ObservableCollection in the UI thread causes an error, even when using the UI dispatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have an `ObservableCollection` that is declared at the class level. This is a collection of custom controls.

```
private ObservableCollection<AssetCriticalDimensionItemDetail> _details;
private Dispatcher UIDispatcher;
```

A method is called that instantiates a new `ObservableCollection` on the UI thread. I'm also setting the UI dispatcher at this time.

At this point in the code, everything is done synchronously. I captured the thread ID so I can compare it when I'm modifying the collection.

[image]

After this is done, some controls are added to a different collection and then a background thread runs. Once the background thread is done, the user can enter some options in the child control and click "Add." Adding fires an event which calls back to the parent control and modifies the collection.

[image]

You can see from that image that the thread ID is the same as the UI thread, but it won't allow me to modify the collection even though it was created on the UI thread. So I tried calling UIDspatcher.Invoke, but it still gives me the same error.

**This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.**

Comment: Why is your method called `InitializeDetailsAsync()` if you're calling the method synchronously?

Comment: Eh, it calls a background thread which is most of the work. But there's a few items that need to be called on the UI thread before the background thread can do it's work.

Comment: Are you creating controls on a background thread, then showing them on the main UI thread?  If so, that would be your problem.  Any object inheriting from `DispatcherObject` is irrevocably bound to the thread on which it was created.

Comment: @MikeStrobel is that even possible? AFAIK controls check during creation if they are created on the UI thread

Comment: @MikeStrobel I think I found the problem. The controls weren't being created in the background thread. Both the controls and the contorl collection are created on the UI thread. But what I didn't notice was that the control collection was being passed to an object that was created in the background thread. That object was what was being assigned to the UI and not the control collection directly.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys It's not. At least not in this case. You can't create a control in the background thread and then assign to an object in the UI thread.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Although your suggestion wasn't the exact answer, it helped me determine the problem. If you submit an answer, I'l accept it. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you may be creating controls on a background thread, then showing them on the main UI thread.  Alternatively, controls created on the UI thread may be interacting with `Dispatcher`-affine objects created on a background thread.  In either case, that would be your problem: any object inheriting from `DispatcherObject` is irrevocably bound to the thread on which it was created.

> @MikeStrobel is that even possible? AFAIK controls check during creation if they are created on the UI thread

Yes, there is no such thing as "the UI thread" as far as the framework is concerned.  Your application could, in theory, have multiple threads running WPF dispatchers.  The constructor for `DispatcherObject` initializes its `Dispatcher` property to `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`, which creates a `Dispatcher` for the current thread if one does not already exist (though the newly created `Dispatcher`, if created, will not actually be running).